# Normalizing a Product Designer database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm looking to create a database for tracking purposes. For the purposes of this question I have abstracted it a bit and transformed it into a Product Design  tracking database.
I'm trying to make it as normalized and efficient as possible.
Essentially I want to be able to track Employees and what designs they've participated in.The queries I want to run aren't particularly complex. I want to be able to query how many employees participated in the design of a specific model, what models and products an employee has designed, how many employees designed a product, etc. The products would be redesigned every year or half year.

My concern is how I'm managing the many to many relationship between models and employees. In the example provided I have a Design table between the Model and Employee Table. This will essentially be a dump of all Employees designers, which both resolves the many to many relationship (which I understand to be a bit of a bad thing to have) and make query design relatively simple. I also assume I can index it by either Emp_ID or Model_ID to make it more efficient.

However I'm worried this table may get a bit unwieldy over time. In its current role I could make this database very inefficient and probably not notice any degradation in performance. However I'm hoping to make this relatively scale-able as I want to make this easy to admin (whether I admin it or someone else takes over) and I'm hoping to add features over time (a CRM-like functionality for example).

I was thinking I could create a table to for each employee and track design projects by having them in a separate empID_design table, but that also seemed very unwieldy. Essentially every other way I thought up on how to do this ended up with creating a large number of tables versus inserting a Row.

One other thing was I wanted to be able to track project managers. In the current form I thought tracking it in the Design table made sense. I don't think the Project Mgr would change mid-design but is there an elegant way to track it if they did?

Any help or advice you can provide is appreciated. I'm a bit rusty with Database Design and ERD Design, so if you notice something that doesn't make sense, its more likely a mistake I made as opposed a fancy nuanced design I thought up.

To give a basic idea of what each table could be representing:

Company: Black and Decker

Product: Rotary Tool

Model: D-5230

Designed by: George Santos, Kevin Smith, John Rodes

Project Manager: Kevin Smith

Thank you in advance!

ERD Diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/flo4l.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like the intersection table between model and employee ought to be a role table, in which each row has:

- An employee ID
- A model ID
- A role ID: designer, project manager, lead designer, etc

In that way an employee could even have multiple roles on a project.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea. I had not thought of that.
It would still allow the people involved with the design to be tracked as well.

Would that table begin to get too massive at some level?
Is there an elegant way to archive the data?

Maybe create a new Role table every year? or is that more overhead than its worth?

Comment: Probably more overhead than it's worth. A well designed and indexed table can contain many millions or billions of entries and still be quite responsive. Don't limit your design for problems that may never occur.

Comment: Yes, agree with @TommCatt -- also, consider the types of questions you will want to ask of the system in the future, and make sure you are preserving that information.

Comment: Noted. I'm still building out a bit of the design but this has been very valuable feedback.

Comment: I'm looking for a follow up opinion.
I'm trying to implement training into the ERD, and I'm thinking it looks like the way I want to do it will have a circular reference in it.
The new ERD would look similar to this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QXv3u.png-----

What I'm concerned about is linking Training_History as a Many to One with Employee and Trainings linked Many to One with Training_History Like this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/V1PwI.png (which the more I look at it the more it looks wrong). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry the Second link should probably look like this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/UnM7H.png